# SyntaxError: Unexpected token - Google Sheets Script Editor

Tags: google-sheets

I want to create a master tab that takes data from other tabs. Once the data is in the master tab I want to be able to filter the information.

I've done this previously using the code that I am having issues with. I learned how to do this here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rpITkG40rQs

Also the previous project I used this code for still works.

The code I am having trouble with is below. I'm getting the following error now:

**Exception: The starting column of the range is too small.**

**getColumnValue    @ Copy 2 of Code.gs:59**

**getCombinedColumnValues   @ Copy 2 of Code.gs:39**

**(anonymous)   @ Copy 2 of Code.gs:16**

**combineData   @ Copy 2 of Code.gs:15**

previously i got this error:

**Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' line: 14 file: Copy of Code.gs**

line 14 is under the "labels" var and above the loop starting with lables.foreach...

```
function combineData() {
  
  var masterSheet = "Master";
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(masterSheet);

  var lc = ss.getLastColumn();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  
  ss.getRange(2, 1, lr-1, lc).clearContent();
  ss.getRange(1, 49, lr-1, lc).clearContent();

  var labels = ss.getRange(1, 1, 1, lc).getValues()[0];
  
  labels.forEach(function(label,i){
    var colValues = getCombinedColumnValues(label);
    ss.getRange(2, i+1, colValues.length, 1).setValues(colValues);
    Logger.log(colValues);

  }); 
   
}

/// note to self - the problem I was having with the document below was the 'if' statement. The tutorial only has one exclusion. I have several tables to include and exclude. 
function getCombinedColumnValues(label) {
  
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()
  
  var colValues = [];
  
  for(k in sheets){
    
    var sheetName = sheets[k].getSheetName();
    
    // grabs the tabs I want. 
    if ((sheetName == "CBDIO Data")||(sheetName == "CCA Data")||(sheetName == "CHW Data")||(sheetName == "Mujeres en Accion Data")||(sheetName == "Padres Unidos Data")||(sheetName == "CBDIO - Form")){
      
      var tempValue = getColumnValue(label, sheetName)
      
      colValues = colValues.concat(tempValue);
    }    
    
  }; 
  
  return colValues;
  
}


function getColumnValue(label, sheetName) {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);

  var colIndex = getColumnIndex(label, sheetName);
  
  var numRow = ss.getLastRow() - 1;
  
  var colValues = ss.getRange(2, colIndex, numRow, 1).getValues();
  
  return colValues;

}

function getColumnIndex(label, sheetName) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);

  var lc = ss.getLastColumn();
  
  var lookupRangeValues = ss.getRange(1, 1, 1, lc).getValues()[0];
  
  var index = lookupRangeValues.indexOf(label) + 1; 
    
  return index;
}
```

'''

Comment: Do yourself a favor. Make a new *Note to self*: When you have code where the line number is hard to identify, remove all the blank lines, so that there's no confusion and you can get an accurate line number.

Comment: I have run your code through a checker and it does not detect any unexpected tokens. Maybe its best for you to share a copy of the project as there don't seem to be any wrong parentheses.